# While comparing 2 csv file with python misses a match on larger files

Tags: python, csv

I am fairly new to programming and I am currently stumped by an issue.  I wrote a little script in python to compare to csv files which contain usernames for email groups that must be maintained.  The script I wrote was working perfectly for csv files that were in the 200-300 item range, however, I just started testing files with a couple thousand values and my script seems to miss the very last item on each list.

The idea here is that I have 2 csv files, an old list and a new list.  The way I receive the files is a bit finicky, so before processing the lists, I create an new csv form each of the csv's I am dealing with.  So basically a old_clean csv and a new_clean csv.  I then check each item in old_clean against new_clean to see if each item is in the new list, if it's not it get's added to remove.csv to be processed into the email system latter. I then run the test the other way around to find new names which go into add.csv.  The issue I have is that the last name on the list, which is on both the old and new csv file, shows up on the add.csv and the remove.csv.

As I stated, this only happens with larger files.  My code is below, any help would be appreciated.

```
import sys
import csv
import re
import os

###Works in python 2.5###

#create a new csv for cleaned values from first csv entered
o = open("first.csv","w")
data = open(sys.argv[1]).read()
o.write( re.sub(" ","",data) )
o.close()

#create a new csv for cleaned values from second csv entered
n = open("second.csv","w")
data = open(sys.argv[2]).read()
n.write( re.sub(" ","",data) )
n.close()

#create csv of names to remove from group
remove = open("Changes/remove.csv","w")

#create csv of names to add to group
add = open("Changes/add.csv","w")

time.sleep(3)

#adds any names from first list not found in second list to the remove.csv
for line in open("first.csv"):
    if line not in open("second.csv"):    
        remove.write(line)
remove.close()        

#adds any names from second list not found in first list to the add.csv        
for line in open ("second.csv"):
    if line not in open("first.csv"):
        add.write(line)
add.close()        

#remove the generated "clean" csv files
os.remove("first.csv")
os.remove("second.csv")
```

Comment: Could it be that the last line in __one__ of your input files is not terminated by a newline?

Comment: I don't think that is the issue, as the file that is actually used is created programmatically the same way with small and large files.  Maybe I should try to add entries below the last item on the list, manually, and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Interesting, I added identical values to the end of both csv files and it seemed to fix the issue. Then removed them in the same manor and it is still working properly.  On the step where I clean the file, am I doing something wrong that is causing that error?

Comment: No idea, the code looks fine to me. Maybe comparing `first.csv` and `second.csv` to the original data could provide some insight.